# Product of Heavisides: calculus vs Fourier transform vs wavefront set

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, fourier-analysis, schwartz-distributions, micro-local-analysis

I decided to ask this question here, since I did not get any answer from MSE and perhaps this topic is somewhat far from MSE's topics. I am following the paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.1778). I am trying to understand how to make sense of products of distributions, using Heaviside function as an example (it is my first time as a physics PhD student trying to fight functional-analytic subtleties). This is particularly relevant for me when trying to work with stuff related to algebraic framework in quantum field theory (AQFT).

The crucial thing about Heaviside function $\Theta(x)$ that I am interested in is the fact that naively, we have in "calculus sense" $\Theta(x)^2 = \Theta(x)$. After all, it is discontinuous only at zero. So it looks like since this function is discontinuous at the origin, I have no real expectation of it obeying Leibniz rule, something like $(\Theta^2)'=2\Theta(x)\Theta(x)'\,\, ``=" 2\Theta(x)\delta(x)$, where the last "equality" is obtained by cheating (using weak derivative). But in general one cannot really make sense of $\Theta(x)\delta(x)$ as products of distributions, so I don't expect Leibniz rule to hold.

However, one (clever) way I learnt from the short review paper above is that we define products in slightly roundabout way: we consider product of distribution in terms of the Fourier transform: that is, if I have two distributions $u,v\in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then one way to do it is to use the fact that the Fourier transform of products is convolution of the Fourier transforms:
\begin{align}
\widetilde{uv} = \widetilde{u}\star\widetilde{v}\,. 
\end{align}
Hence the product, whenever it makes sense, is defined to be the inverse Fourier transform of the $\widetilde{u}\star \widetilde{v}$.

A simple try (using *Mathematica*) shows that
\begin{align}
\tilde\Theta(k) = \pi  \delta (k)+\frac{i}{k}
\end{align}
where I used the same convention for Fourier transform
\begin{align}
\tilde{u}(k) = \int dx\,e^{ikx}u(x)\,.
\end{align}
However, using this precription via inverse Fourier transform of the convolution in this case give (see Eq.~(1) in the paper)
\begin{align}
\Theta^{2}(x) = \frac{1}{2}\Theta\,.
\end{align}
So this disagrees with the intuitive picture I got earlier.

I will not go into the wavefront set yet (I am still learning it), but it seems that Hörmander's result is supposed to give a prescription that respects Leibniz rule, while both naive and Fourier transform methods do not obey Leibniz rule. From this alone, it seems that  essentially Heaviside function falls outside Hörmander's requirement. However, I cannot see why the Fourier transform method gives different prescription from naive one.

**Question:** what is the underlying reason behind the difference in Fourier method vs the naive one, and any other approaches (e.g., wavefront sets)? I expect that this shouldn't be "too ambiguous" because I am not multiplying ill-defined objects like $\delta(x)\Theta(x)$ or $\delta(x)\delta(x)$, but something that could at least looks sensible in calculus. Perhaps one way to ask is this: in what sense is $\theta^2=\Theta$ rigorous as a product of distributions?

One possibility I can think of is that this is the analog of ambiguity in prescribing the value of an asymptotic (divergent) series: sums like $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n$ can be assigned different finite values depending on which method you use to sum them (e.g., Cesaro gives $1/2$, while naive rearrangement can give $0,\pm 1$, or more generally any rational number.)

Any clarification (even if it is only sensible in terms of more advanced tools like microlocal analysis) would be appreciated, since I can then try to look in the right direction.

**UPDATE:** As mentioned earlier, I was experimenting this with *Mathematica*, and as Willie Wong pointed out it cannot be right since $i/k$ is not locally integrable so the convolution does not work. From my perspective it means something worse: the naive calculus version does not fit Fourier transform method either (which cannot be done because of $i/k$). How should I understand these different approaches? I have updated the question to account for this stupid miss on my part.

---

Comment: $i/k$ is not locally integrable. How did you compute the convolution of $\tilde{\Theta}$ against itself?

Comment: The m.se post is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4413970/product-of-heavisides-naive-vs-fourier-transform-vs-wavefront-set

Comment: @WillieWong I was just testing this using Mathematica, and apparently it spits out something proportional to $\tilde{\Theta}$. You are right though that it's not locally integrable, it's my stupid miss. I will reframe the question.

Comment: at $x=0$ your result $\Theta^2=\Theta/2$ does make sense (since $\Theta(0)=1/2$ is a natural definition)

Comment: I've lost track of what the question is. Originally, the question was that there were two mutually inconsistent proposals for what $\Theta^{2} $ means, and what the resolution of the inconsistency would be. Now, there is only one proposal. So, what is the question now?

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt the issue is that I am aware of three approaches, originally two methods that disagree + one method (wavefront) that does not work by assumption. Now only one method "works" (calculus one), but the other two don't. Actually, the "wrong" FT one I did matches "limiting sequences of smooth functions" (like $\frac{1}{2}(1+\tanh(x/n))$ which gives $\Theta(0) = 1/2$. My question is how to make sense of these differences. For example, should I believe or discard "calculus one" if I am being rigorous?

Comment: If you use the word rigorous around here, you'd have to specify what space precisely you intend your $\Theta $ to be defined in. But for practical purposes, of course $\Theta^{2} =\Theta $, and the value at the one contentious point, $x=0$, should never matter for anything you calculate (you should be integrating against a sufficiently smooth function, so that the (finite) value at one point shouldn't matter). If you find your result does depend on $\Theta (x=0)$, then you've gone astray somewhere and you should investigate/regularize/consult your physics application as to the meaning.